# Testing AngularJS with different dependency values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Say I have a provider that gets configured at runtime and sets certain values inside itself. The provider has a `get` method exposed so that these values are accessible inside an angular controller.

When testing the controller, is there anyway to test the different cases of the provider's value efficiently?

The only way to get it to test correctly is to redefine the appController per test case as redefining the get method in the provider to return what I want it to doesn't seem to work (which tells me that when a controller is constructed it takes the dependencies by value, not by reference).

```
describe("myController", function(){
    "use strict";
    describe("AppController", function(){

        var appController;
        var $rootScope;
        var $scope;
        var providerMock;


        beforeEach(function(){
            module('myController');
            inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
                $controller = _$controller_;
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            });

        });

        describe('provider value is a', function(){
            beforeEach(function(){
                providerMock = { get: function(){ return 'a';}};
                appController = $controller('appController', {
                    $scope: $scope,
                    provider: providerMock
                });
            });
            it('isA should be true', function(){
                expect($scope.isA).toEqual(true);
            )};
        });

        describe('provider value is b', function(){
            beforeEach(function(){
                providerMock = { get: function(){ return 'b';}};
                appController = $controller('appController', {
                    $scope: $scope,
                    provider: providerMock
                });
            });
            it('isA should be false', function(){
                expect($scope.isA).toEqual(false);
            )};
        });
    });
});
```

as you can see, redefining `appController` in the two describes seems repetitive. Is there any way around this?

Also, let's say I have another test case that is unrelated to the provider altogether, for example if I'm testing a function. Which appController instantiation branch should I put it under? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

`$controller` local dependencies have their use cases, but this is what module mocks are for.

```
var providerMockedValue;

...

module('myController', { provider: { get: function(){ return providerMockedValue;}} } );

...

providerMockedValue = 'a';
appController = $controller('appController', { $scope: $scope });
```